# Using Openai Spaces for a modified environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have a 2-dimensional array of normalized data. I am using

```
space = np.array([0,1,...366],[0,0.000001,.....1])
```

I need to fit this as an observation space in reinforcement learning. I have extended the open ai gym and created a custom made environment. How to fit in this 2-dimensional array in openAI spaces. Can I use Box, DiscreteSpace or MultiDiscrete space? Can anyone help me with a sample code to fit this in observation space?